# How to find specific substrings in XML files that aren't inside comments?

Tags: xml, xpath, comments

In my XML, I have comments like `<!--INS--><!--/INS--><!--DEL--><!--/DEL-->`; I want to ignore any matching text within it when I'm searching for specific substrings.

For example, my XML file has:

```
<p>XXXX YYYY ZZZZ 
<!--INS-->,,<!--/INS-->
<!--DEL-->..<!--/DEL-->
AAA BBB CCC DDD..
</p>
```

I want to find the double dot elements (p tag) but need to ignore double dot within both "INS" and "DEL" tags.

I have tried my xpath

```
//p[contains(.,'..') and descendant::comment()[not(contains(.,'..'))]]
```

but it is not working. How can I do this in Xpath code?

Comment: What XPath version are you using.

Comment: Xpath version 2.0

Comment: I would replace `<!--INS-->` by `<INS>` and `<!--/INS-->` by `</INS>` using regular expressions so you have markup that properly reflects the logical structure; the query then becomes much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ".." and ",," are not inside comment()'s, they are in text()-nodes between comment()'s.
So if understand correctly you need this(wrong assumption see EDIT):

```
//p[ends-with(normalize-space(),'..') and not(comment()[contains('INSDEL',.) and following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()[.='..']]])]
```

This wil not match your example.

Explanation of this part:

```
following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()
```

It will select the text()-node that is direct following of that comment.

If you want that only this will not match (both ..)(also wrong assumption see EDIT)

```
<p>XXXX YYYY ZZZZ 
<!--INS-->..<!--/INS-->
<!--DEL-->..<!--/DEL-->
AAA BBB CCC DDD..
</p>
```

You need:

```
    //p[ends-with(normalize-space(),'..') and 
not(comment()[.='INS' and following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()[.='..']]] 
and comment()[.='DEL' and following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()[.='..']]])]
```

**EDIT:**

The following XPath:

```
//p[text()[not(preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::comment()=('INS','DEL') ] ) and contains(.,'..')]]
```

will match this example:

```
  <p>Save at least 15% on local breaks, longer trips, or anything in between.. Plan your next getaway for less.
    <!--INS-->Book between Mar.. 15 - 31<!--/INS-->
    <!--DEL-->Stay between May. 15-31<!--/DEL--> Getaway Deals. </p>
```

because the two dots are in text()-nodes that are not between comments

But wil not match

```
  <p>Save at least 15% on local breaks, longer trips, or anything in between. Plan your next getaway for less.
    <!--INS-->Book between Mar.. 15 - 31<!--/INS-->
    <!--DEL-->Stay between May. 15-31<!--/DEL--> Getaway Deals. </p>
```

Because the only double dots are in text()-nodes between the comments

Comment: Thanks siebe jongebloed, but I have tested the code for real scenario and not working '<p>Save at least 15% on local breaks, longer trips, or anything in between.. Plan your next getaway for less. 
<!--INS-->Book between Mar.. 15 - 31<!--/INS-->
<!--DEL-->Stay between May.. 15-31<!--/DEL-->
Getaway Deals.
</p>'    Could you guide me

Comment: I tested these XPath’s against your example and they worked. Please share that scenario and tell witch of the two options that I gave, is the right one

Comment: In this new xml, what do you expect?
Should this not be matched because in the p-element there are double dots and those dots are also between the comments?

Comment: I have to search within <p> tag for the presence of double dot but not within the values of  descendant tags INS and DEL comments. These tags are comments need to be ignored during match

Comment: Awaiting for your help siebe jongebloed

Comment: I  have changed the answer. Does the code after EDIT answer your problem?

Comment: Fulfilled all my requirements. Thank u very much @Siebe Jongebloed

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring for a moment the particular comment type I think an XPath expression would be

```
//p[descendant::text()[contains(., '..')][not(preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::comment()] and following-sibling::node()[1][self::comment()])]]
```

To match only those `INS` and `DEL` comments you could extend it to

```
//p[descendant::text()[contains(., '..')][not(preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::comment()[. = ('INS', 'DEL')]] and following-sibling::node()[1][self::comment()[. = ('/INS', '/DEL')]])]]
```

In the end I would be tempted to preprocess the input with XSLT or XQuery to cleanly wrap the dot between the comment "pairs" into a container, then the XPath selection is much easier.